# ¿Cómo traducir "bluff"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Estoy traduciendo las reglas para un juego  con frases como "don't be afraid to bluff" o "is this a bluff?" (como en poker), pero no sé si dejarlo tal cual, o usar "engaño" o "mentira".

Sé que farol es la palabra de diccionario que corresponde, pero no sé qué tan común sea su utilización. Dudo que mucha gente sepa su significado en este contexto.

**Nota**: La traducción es para una aplicación de iOS, o sea, una audiencia universal.

**Nota 2:** Gracias a todos por sus sugerencias, y tal parece que en cada región existe una manera particular de expresarlo, así que decidí usar "Mentir". No es tan sutil como "Bluff", pero al menos será común en todos los países.

Comment: Uy. Esta está difícil. En Colombia se utiliza "cañar" o "meter caña" en frases como "me estas _cañando_, sé que no tienes los cuatro ases", pero casi seguramente en ningún otro país se usa esta expresión.

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias, pero como dices, esa expresión es muy local...

Comment: En España "farol" es un término muy común que se usa tanto para el juego de cartas como coloquialmente. Expresiones como "Que no te dé miedo echarte/marcarte un farol" o "¿Es un farol?" son muy comunes en el día a día y lo entendería cualquier persona. Por lo que veo en las repuestas "farol" no es tan común en otros países. Sería bueno que especificaras a qué país va dirigido (o si necesitas alguna expresión universal).

Comment: @Yay Gracias por la sugerencia, lo aclaré en la pregunta. Es una audiencia universal, así que no que farol funcione. ¿Crees que 'disimulo' funcione, como sugieren en una de las respuestas?

Comment: Funciona, pero desde luego es más inespecífico que "bluff". A lo mejor en el contexto adecuado "que no te dé miedo disimular" se entendería, pero en frío es difícil saberlo. También está "engañar", "fingir" o incluso "liar a tus oponentes", pero tampoco son mucho más específicas.

Comment: En Chile decimos simplemente "_poner cara de póquer_".

Comment: @Rodrigo, creo que "poner cara de póquer" es más general que un "bluf" ya que se puede usa para no dejar entrever que tienes tanto una mano buena como mala. En un farol tienes malas cartas, e intentas amedrentar al contrincante haciéndole pensar que son buenas, para que no envite. Pero está la posibilidad contraria, que tengas cartas muy buenas, pero pones "cara de poker" para que el otro no se de cuenta y envite o vea tu envite, pensando que son normalitas o buenas. La cara de poker es básicamente que el otro no sepa tus verdaderas intenciones por tus reacciones.

Comment: @Diego OK, no es lo mismo. (Me costó un rato entender.)

Comment: @Rodrigo, posiblemente porque donde dije "pensando que son normalitas o buenas" debería decir "nomalitas o malas". Si pensase que son buenas el oponente no envidaría, pese a la cara de poker. Me expliqué mal.

Answer (score 8):

Yo creo que `tirarse / echarse / marcarse un farol` o `ir de farol` (incluso *farolear*) es lo que mejor funcionaría en este contexto. Es un término ampliamente aceptado en juegos de cartas (poker, mus). La rae lo [acepta claramente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HdnxIzT) con el significado de

> En el juego, envite falso hecho para desorientar o atemorizar.

Si quieres algún sinónimo para la acción de "pretender tener más posibilidades de las que realmente tienes para engañar a los otros competidores" podrías intentar usar:

- fanfarronear
- achantar o amedrentar (Acobardar o apabullar a alguien)
- envalentonarse
- exagerar un envite

Si no, siempre te queda la opción de usar la definición de la rae y explicar la acción, más que buscar un sinónimo:

> No tengas miedo de *exagerar* (o *fanfarronear*) un envite para *amedrentar* a tus competidores.  <sub>Don't be afraid to bluff</sub>
>
> Esto es una fanfarronada.  <sub>This is a bluff</sub>

Comment: La única de estas opciones que seria "casi' bien interpretada en américa latina sería _fanfarronear_. Nunca antes había escuchado "farol" o "farolear", por lo que les garantizo que por estos lados esa no funciona.

Comment: @DGaleano en ese caso la traducción tendrá que explicar la acción, en lugar de usar un término o verbo que la resuma, o asumir que se entiende el contexto (sin el contexto adecuado no funcionan acciones tipo "engañar", "fingir" o "aparentar", porque no recogen del todo el matiz de _amedrentar o intimidar_ a un competidor). En España se usa el "dar o meter caña" que usáis en Colombia, pero con un significado completamente distinto. En México por lo visto se usa _bolfeo_ de acuerdo a wordreference, que tampoco es término "universal".

Comment: La verdad es que últimamente se oye ya bastante la palabra inglesa: "ese político ha sido un bluff: parecía que iba a hacer grandes cosas pero se quedó en nada", etc. Para esta acepción, fanfarrón estaría cerca, pero perdería algo de significado.

Comment: Se ha acostumbrado a extranjerizar la palabra *bluff* simplemente como *blufeo*, y posterior a ello se entrega la información en palabras simples.

Answer (score 4):

Quizás la tradución más directa de *bluff* sea *bluf*, dado que **bluf es un anglicismo aceptado por la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5hYiNmF)**:

> **bluf**
>
> Del ingl. *bluff*.
>
> 1. m. Montaje propagandístico destinado a crear un prestigio que posteriormente se revela falso.
> 2. m. Persona o cosa revestida de un prestigio falto de fundamento.
> 3. m. Fanfarronada, acción intimidatoria hecha por quien no cuenta con los medios para cumplir su amenaza.

Answer (score 3):

*farol* suena horrible. (Pero debe ser de uso regional.) Puedes usar como verbo *disimular*:

> *Are you **bluffing**? = ¿Estás **disimulando**?*

Ahora como sustantivo, simplemente puedes usar ***disimulo***.

Comment: En toda España se utiliza farol.

Answer (score 2):

## English

Here in Argentina I believe the most accurate translation to "bluff" (as in poker when someone is bluffing while placing a bet) may be "alardear".

By RAE, alardear: "Hacer ostentación, presumir de algo"

---

## Español

Aquí en Argentina creo que la traducción más precisa para *bluff* (como en el póquer cuando alguien está *alardeando* mientras coloca una apuesta) puede ser *alardear*.

Según la RAE, *alardear*: "Hacer ostentación, presumir de algo"

Comment: Bienvenido al Spanish SE. Esta pregunta está hecha en español por lo que tu respuesta podría haberse hecho en español también.

Comment: @DGaleano Me tomé la molestia de dejarlo en español.

Comment: Yo no creo que `alardear` sea la traducción más precisa. El "bluff" consiste en engaño e intimidación. Si uno hace "ostentación" es porque puede. En un "bluff" presumes de algo que no tienes (y no quieres que el otro sepa que no lo tienes). Aparte, el término carece de la connotación de intentar amedrentar a los contrarios con ese pavoneo. El término puede valer si entendemos el contexto, pero no me parece mejor que ninguno de los ya expuestos, y ni de lejos "la traducción más precisa".

Comment: En Argentina, cuando se juega al "truco" (a tradicional card game where you bluff even more than in poker) la palabra de elección es simplemente "mentir". (p.ej: ¡Truco! -- Me estás mintiendo: ¡retruco!) Pero el truco es un juego regional... no sé si alguien de otras partes lo entendería igual a ese "mentir".